# How to find info about unknown motherboard

Tags: motherboard

How do I find out my motherboard manufacture model and other related information? This XFX motherboard was bought several years back and I've totally lost every documents related to it.

Is there any software or anything that will help me to get me all the motherboard specification?

EDIT : I am running on windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably visual inspection - a lot of motherboards have the model number screenprinted very visibly on the PCB!

Aside from that, there are a good number of ways to do it in software - if you're running Windows (taking a guess here, please add more detail to the question if you're not) the system summary of msinfo32 will probably show the model number.

Comment: how do I know on which IC I should look on? The biggest with lot of things written on, that one?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be it.  I'm curious what you're hoping to accomplish with this information if you're non-technical enough that you had to ask (not that there's anything WRONG with that, mind you!)

Comment: I want to post another question in [Steam forum](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=14), cause a game that I have just downloaded, is not running. I didn't wanted to post my problem without specifying my pc configuration. :)

Comment: If /that's/ your goal, I would download a tool like Speccy (http://www.piriform.com/speccy) - should give you everything you could possibly need.